# Split a string into two specified strings with the minimum number of slices

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, tree, trie

We have a string `s` and two strings `t1` and `t2`, which are made from slices of string `s`. I need to find the minimum number of slices that need to be made to get `t1` and `t2`.

For example:

```
s = "ababbaba"
t1 = "abbb"
t2 = "abaa"
```

We can make 5 slices: `ab abb a b a`

Then we can get `t1`: `abb b`

and `t2`: `ab a a`

we can also make 5 slices as `ab a bb a ba` so there are multiple solutions with 5 slices to be taken into account.

OR

```
s = "stopgame"
t1 = "sam"
t2 = "topge"
```

```
s: s topg am e
t1: s am
t2 topg e
```

Is there a fast algorithm for searching the minimum number of required substrings?

Update: I found a data structure that might be helpful - trie or prefix tree. But I don’t know yet how it can be applied.

Comment: I don't think prefix tree is good idea. Unless your prefix tree also support for matching characters in the middle of string, But usually they only match by prefix

Comment: _"minimum number of required substrings"_ - Did you mean, numbers (1,2,3) or substrings ("abc","xyz") ?

Comment: @Nur I need the number of substrings. There are 5 substrings in the first example and 4 substrings in the second.

Comment: What if, The answer is `4` for the first example ?  `s = ab a bb aba`  `t1 = ab bb` `t2 = ab a a`

Comment: No, the sequence of letters must be as in the original word